# how to add android platform for ionic project

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, npm

I met this error when i want to add android plaform

```
F:\OLLE\olle>cordova platform add android
Using cordova-fetch for cordova-android@7.0.0
(node:15100) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): CordovaError: Failed to fetch platform cordova-android@7.0.0
Probably this is either a connection problem, or platform spec is incorrect.
Check your connection and platform name/version/URL.
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 4294963238 Error output:
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to F:\OLLE\olle\node_modules\extglob
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to F:\OLLE\olle\node_modules\recast

npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to cess to F:\OLLE\olle\node_modules\unreachable-branch-transform
Some other same errors...
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to F:\OLLE\olle\node_modules\cordova-android
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to F:\OLLE\olle\node_modules\ionic-angular
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to F:\OLLE\olle\node_modules\ionicons
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to F:\OLLE\olle\node_modules\rxjs
npm WARN The package protractor is included as both a dev and production dependency.

npm ERR! path F:\OLLE\olle\node_modules\extglob
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! syscall access
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, access 'F:\OLLE\olle\node_modules\extglob'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-04-15T05_45_21_245Z-debug.log
(node:15100) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code
```

At first, this command run good. After i removed the android platform, it went wrong when i tried to re-add the android platform. Does anyone konw how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete Android folder after that rm nodemoduls and again add if it willbe not working then create new project and paste src folder and add all plugin after that working fine .

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Praveen, I would do the same:

```
ionic cordova platform rm android
rm -rf node_modules
ionic cordova platform add android
```

Also remember to use cordova commands with ionic. It probably makes the process more complete.

Also check your permissions for the folder you made the project, but maybe adding ionic before cordova will fix something.